# Which tube experiences a larger buoyant force?

Tags: forces, buoyancy

[image]

I saw lots of debate about this question. Some are saying that this cannot be solved because the weight of the tubes is not given. Others say the red one experiences more buoyant force because for red: buoyant force=W while for blue: buoyant force+normal force=W. There are also people saying that blue experiences more buoyant force because it displaces more water than red. Can someone please explain which one is correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buoyancy

From the first paragraph: "[The buoyancy force]...
is equivalent to the weight of the fluid that would otherwise occupy the submerged volume of the object, i.e. the displaced fluid."

And the weight of the displaced fluid is entirely determined by the displaced volume...

Answer (score 0):

If the two tubes are identical (except for the weight) and the red one is floating with some of it extending above the fluid surface, then the blue one is displacing more fluid and experiences a greater buoyant force.

Answer (score 0):

Like many have mentioned, buoyancy is EQUAL to the weight of the displaced fluid, nothing more, nonthing less.

But there is another issue may play a role. The buoyancy is but a name of convenience given to the net force of pressure exerted by a still fluid, (which means moving fluid will dramatically change the situation.) So the the blue tube is tightly adhered to the bottom so that there is no way water can flow beneath it, then it does not get any buoyancy at all.